# Oracle SQL check empty and return value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

Can you please help to write a query with the below.

I want to check the two columns Date and Description to check if empty/null, if both column value is empty/null return a value as YES.

```
COLUMN_NAME      DATATYPE      NULLABLE
Date              Date          Yes
Description     Varchar2(100)   Yes
```

Please help

Comment: Define "empty".  An empty string (a string of 0 length that is not `NULL`) is treated as `NULL` in Oracle-- there is no separate empty string.  And I'm not sure what it would mean to have an empty `DATE`.  Are you asking how to determine whether both columns are `NULL`?

Comment: Yes check for both column as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT other_column1, other_column2
     , CASE WHEN "DATE" IS NULL AND description IS NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS both_columns_null
  FROM mytable
```

The column named `DATE` is in double quotes because "DATE" is a reserved word in Oracle.